# How can I import Alfresco SDK 1.0 into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, development-environment, alfresco-share

I'm new to Alfresco development and according to my research so far, to develop customizations for Alfresco 4.x I  need to use Alfresco SDK 1.0. I was trying to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utYZaVe9Nd0) but as the version is different I have not been able to  import it so  far.

Been trying a lot of things but when I import it as any other import it comes with too many errors.

Can anyone give me ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous edition of alfresco where supporting java based SDK and not maven.For any Java base SDK of alfresco ,you have to download that from alfresco wiki.For an example for alfresco version 3.4 you will find that in below link.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Community_3.4.e_Download.

After downloading you need to import project from `alfresco-community-sdk-3.4.b\lib` directory.Once open import dialog ,a list of project will appear.Select the highlighted one as below.

[image]

After importing this project,Create new java base project,and select imported project as parent project of new Java based Project.

Comment: Thanks for you answer I'm going to  check it out and will try  your recomendation.  TYvm

Comment: comment if you face any issue.

Comment: Ty Krutik, it works just perfect !  I can start working with it now  and will be around if any more problems show up (they sure will). Ty.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for latest SDK 1.2 which is maven based SDK for alfresco 4.x versions.
Check this out
http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I  am actually following Jeff Pots tutorial and it was because of it I  noticed that I  need  a diferent version.                                                      I will check  about SDK 1.2 and see what  can I  find. Tyvm